# ReferenceError: require is not defined in MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, require, node-mongodb-native

I try to connect MongoDB from Mongo client on windows command (Window 8.1). When I use `require()` in javascript, I have error as below. Does any one has same issue? Did I miss any `require` related **npm** installation? How can't MongoDB shell find `require` function?

```
C:\tutorial\nodeMongoAngular-master\lesson2>mongo

MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
connecting to: test
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

2015-04-30T14:33:25.812-0400 E QUERY    ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at (shell):1:19
```

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing the [`mongo`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/) administrative shell with the [Node.js driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/). While both environments happen to use JavaScript, the `mongo` shell has more limited I/O support and is  not intended to be used as a driver for application development.

If you want to write Node.js applications using the MongoDB driver (as per your example code), you need to use the `node` interpreter. The Node.js driver documentation includes a [Quickstart tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb#quickstart) with examples that should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

@Scott Lee: if you're still looking for an answer, try running with command "node yourscript.js". Make sure mongod is running. 'mongo script.js' will work for pure mongo scripts without nodejs code.